# Entity Framework Multi Level Eager Loading, Linq to Entities

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, eager-loading

When i eager load two child entities whom both contain a child entity of the same type, the first one is ignored.

Ex:

```
public class Geometry
{
    public Square square {get; set;}
    public Circle circle {get; set;}
}

public class Square
{
    public Size size { get; set; }
}

public class Circle
{
    public Size size {get; set;}
}

public class Size
{
    public int length {get; set;}
    public int width {get; set;}
}

dbSet.get().Include(x => x.circle.size).Include(x => x.square.size)
```

What i have noticed is that in the sql generated, there is a left outer join of size on circle but there is no left outer join of size on square.

I was just wondering if there something to correct this issue,
thanx in advance